# codeigniter file upload not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter. I want to upload file with two file input fields in a form. My code uploads files in my directory correctly but in model function parameter not geting  file name.

my code

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
$config['max_size'] = '0';
$config['encrypt_name'] = True;

$up=$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$fileNameheaderimage = $this->upload->data();

$config2['upload_path'] = './uploads';
$config2['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif';
$config2['max_size'] = '0';
$config2['encrypt_name'] = True;

$up2=$this->load->library('upload', $config2);
$fileNameprofileimage = $this->upload->data();

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('headerimage') || !$this->upload->do_upload('profileimage') )
{
        $status = "0";
        $msg = "File upload failed";
} 
else 
{


    $result = $this->api_model->updateprofileinfo($fileNameheaderimage['file_name'],$fileNameheaderimage['file_name']);
    if($result)
    {
        $status = "1";
        $msg = "File uploaded";
    }
    else 
    {
        $status = "0";
        $msg = "File upload failed";
    }


}
```

Here file name blank

```
$this->api_model->updateprofileinfo($fileNameheaderimage['file_name'],$fileNameheaderimage['file_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

no need load again `upload` library `$this->load->library('upload');` Use `initilize()` method to changes config

```
$this->upload->initialize($config)
//and 
$this->upload->initialize($config2)
```

In you case 1st config overwrite with 2nd config so it won't work, try this way

```
$this->load->library('upload');

$this->upload->initialize($config)
$status1 = true; $status2 = true;
if (!$this->upload->do_upload('headerimage') )
{
        $status1 = "0";
} 

$this->upload->initialize($config2)
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('profileimage'){
        $status2 = "0";
}
if($status1 == true || $status2 == true){
   $msg = "File uploaded";
}else{
   $msg = "File not uploaded";
}
```

Comment: how can i pass file name with $this->api_model->updateprofileinfo()

Comment: save `data` in different variables and assign